# AngularJS: Differences between $scope.$on and document.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling

I am new to Javascript and AngularJS. Both seem to me as an event listener. What are the differences? Can I use them interchangeably? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$scope.$on will catch events that are.$broadcast() on the $scope whereas addEventListener listens to any events on the page. They're similar but not interchangeable.

If working in an angular app, I would definitely use $scope.$on unless otherwise needed, i.e. catching events from outside of the angular app.  You will gain testability if you're writing unit tests and will only be looking for events from your own code, which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No. They operate on different objects, and are not interchangeable, although they are very similar in *what* they do. Both add an event listener to an object which can emit events, but scopes are not HTMLElements (like `document`), and different events are fired on scopes than on HTMLElements.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.$on` should be used wherever possible. Usually if there is an Angular way to do something, you should do it that way.

`$scope.$on` is used in conjunction with `$scope.$emit` which sends data to all parent controllers, and `$scope.$broadcast` which sends data to all child controllers. This gives you greater control over the flow of data through the app. Furthermore, handling events inside of a native event listener will break 2-way data binding.